# After fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream), memoryStream is null

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

So, I have the function, which gets `BitmapImage`, I need to save it to iso storage and convert to Base64 (for sending to server). However, copying from `fileStream` to `memoryStream` is not successful.

```
public void SetImage(BitmapImage bitmap)
{
    if (isoFiles.FileExists(Settings.FILE_AVATAR_JPG))
        isoFiles.DeleteFile(Settings.FILE_AVATAR_JPG);

    var fileStream = isoFiles.CreateFile(Settings.FILE_AVATAR_JPG);
    var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
    wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, 120, 120, 0, 85); // file is saved 

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);          // here, memoryStream is null
    byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    fileStream.Close();

    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Stream.CopyTo` copies from the current position of `fileStream` which has been changed by `SaveJpeg()` so you need to reset it;

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

fileStream.Position = 0;
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
```